# jsonapi and active_mode_serializers how to get relationship attributes in the response?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers, json-api

tech context: rails 4.2.2, active_model_serializers 0.10.0.rc2
Given a cart and a list of product when I add a product to the cart I expect to get as response:

```
{
"data": {
  "id": "575",
  "type": "carts",
  "attributes": {
    "name": "cart 1"
  },
  "relationships": {
    "cart_products": {
      "data": [
        {
          "type": "cart_products",
          "id": "32",
          "attributes": {
            "product_id": 456
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
}
```

unfortunately ,
the current response is

```
{
"data": {
"id": "575",
"type": "carts",
"attributes": {
  "name": "cart 1"
},
"relationships": {
  "cart_products": {
    "data": [
      {
        "type": "cart_products",
        "id": "32",

      }
    ]
  }
}
```

}
}

is there a way to have relationship attributes rendered?

Comment: Did you get the solution??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The JSON:API Spec explains how the relationship data should be. What you are asking for is actually meant to be nested, or better yet "Included" as per the spec.

I would suggest you read a bit over there http://jsonapi.org/format/#document-compound-documents for more details on the spec regarding included/nested relationships

Also, regarding your question, you need to tell your serializer to render included elements, like so: `render @posts, include: ['authors', 'comments']` 
See here for more info: https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers

Comment: hi @infinityzxx: I have added command like render branch, include: ['installations'] in my controller. But I didn't get all the attributes of installations table. Did I miss something

Comment: I'm unfortunately not a rails guru, I'd suggest you create your own question on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

According to the manual:

```
render json: @posts, include: ['author', 'comments', 'comments.author']
  # or
render json: @posts, include: 'author,comments,comments.author'
```

More details:

1. http://jsonapi.org/format/#document-compound-documents
2. https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/a032201a91cbca407211bca0392ba881eef1f7ba/docs/general/adapters.md#included